# winforms refresh multiple panels

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a poker game where I need to show multiple poker hands at the same time. I can either show 1, 3, 5, or 10.

I have 1 main hand that will display all the time and I activate different views based on the amount of hands the player wants to play.

I have 2 main panels (main_hand_panel, and extra_hands_panel)

I add all the Panels in a `List` and when it's time, I call `ShowHand` on it.

I add the first poker hand to main_hand_panel like this:

```
Point startPosition = new Point(0, 0);
ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainScreen));
var mainPokerHand = new PokerPanel(startPosition, main_hand_panel.Size, offset, cardSize);
mainPokerHand.Initialize(resources);
this.main_hand_panel.Controls.Add(mainPokerHand);
allHands.Add(mainPokerHand);
```

Then depending on which screen I'm showing I draw and add the additional hands like this (five hands example shown)

```
public void DrawFivePlay(ComponentResourceManager resources)
{
    Point startPosition = new Point(0, 0);
    var containerSize = extra_hands_panel.Size;
    containerSize.Height = Convert.ToInt32(containerSize.Height / 2);
    containerSize.Width = Convert.ToInt32(containerSize.Width / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        startPosition.Y = containerSize.Height * i;
        var pokerHand = new PokerPanel(startPosition, containerSize, scale(offset, .30), scale(cardSize, .8));
        pokerHand.Initialize(resources);
        this.extra_hands_panel.Controls.Add(pokerHand);
        allHands.Add(pokerHand);
    }

    startPosition.X = containerSize.Width;
    startPosition.Y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        startPosition.Y = containerSize.Height * i;
        var pokerHand = new PokerPanel(startPosition, containerSize, scale(offset, .30), scale(cardSize, .8));
        pokerHand.Initialize(resources);
        this.extra_hands_panel.Controls.Add(pokerHand);
        allHands.Add(pokerHand);
    }
}
```

When I'm ready to show the hands, I call reveal_click which goes through all the hands in List and displays them.

```
private void reveal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var hand in allHands)
    {
        hand.ShowHand();
    }
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

The interesting part is that it doesn't display the main hand, it will display all the others, but the only time it displays the first hand is when the program just started and we are playing only 1 hand.  If I show any of the other play option, the first hand will not display anymore.

Here is the PokerPanel code:

```
namespace TEX_DrawPoker
{
    public class PokerPanel : Panel
    {
        private PictureBox pictureBox1_5;
        private PictureBox pictureBox1_1;
        private PictureBox pictureBox1_2;
        private PictureBox pictureBox1_3;
        private PictureBox pictureBox1_4;

        Timer drawTimer = new Timer();
        int timerTick = 0;
        string[] pokerHand;

        Size panelSize = new Size(5*229, 275);
        Size cardSize = new Size(146, 202);
        Point startPosition = new Point(0, 3);
        Point firstCardPosition = new Point(0, 0);
        Point offset  = new Point(160, 0);

        public PokerPanel(Point _startPosition,Size _panelSize, Point _offset, Size _cardSize)
        {
            drawTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(startDisplay);
            drawTimer.Interval = 100;
            drawTimer.Enabled = false;

            panelSize = _panelSize;
            cardSize = _cardSize;
            offset = _offset;
            startPosition = _startPosition;
        }

        public void startDisplay(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (timerTick)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.pictureBox1_1.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(".\\img\\cards\\" + pokerHand[timerTick] + ".png"), cardSize));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.pictureBox1_2.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(".\\img\\cards\\" + pokerHand[timerTick] + ".png"), cardSize));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.pictureBox1_3.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(".\\img\\cards\\" + pokerHand[timerTick] + ".png"), cardSize));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.pictureBox1_4.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(".\\img\\cards\\" + pokerHand[timerTick] + ".png"), cardSize));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.pictureBox1_5.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(".\\img\\cards\\" + pokerHand[timerTick] + ".png"), cardSize));
                    break;
            }

            if (timerTick >= 4)
            {
                drawTimer.Stop();
                timerTick = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                timerTick++;
            }
        }

        public void ShowHand()
        {
            pokerHand = Deck.shuffle();
            drawTimer.Start();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Image back = Image.FromFile(".\\img\\cards\\back.png");
            this.pictureBox1_1.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_2.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_3.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_4.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_5.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
        }

        public void Initialize(ComponentResourceManager resources)
        {
            Image back = Image.FromFile(".\\img\\cards\\back.png");

            this.pictureBox1_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox1_2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox1_3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox1_4 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox1_5 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_3)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_4)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_5)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // hand_1
            // 
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1_5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1_4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1_3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1_2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1_1);

            this.Location = startPosition;
            this.Name = "hand_1";
            this.Size = panelSize;
            this.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // pictureBox1_1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1_1.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_1.Location = firstCardPosition;
            this.pictureBox1_1.Name = "pictureBox1_1";
            this.pictureBox1_1.Size = cardSize;
            this.pictureBox1_1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pictureBox1_1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox1_2
            // 
            var positionCard_2 = firstCardPosition;
            positionCard_2.Offset(offset);
            this.pictureBox1_2.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_2.Location = positionCard_2; 
            this.pictureBox1_2.Name = "pictureBox1_2";
            this.pictureBox1_2.Size = cardSize;
            this.pictureBox1_2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.pictureBox1_2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox1_3
            // 
            var positionCard_3 = positionCard_2;
            positionCard_3.Offset(offset);
            this.pictureBox1_3.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_3.Location = positionCard_3;
            this.pictureBox1_3.Name = "pictureBox1_3";
            this.pictureBox1_3.Size = cardSize;
            this.pictureBox1_3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.pictureBox1_3.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox1_4
            // 
            var positionCard_4 = positionCard_3;
            positionCard_4.Offset(offset);

            this.pictureBox1_4.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_4.Location = positionCard_4;
            this.pictureBox1_4.Name = "pictureBox1_4";
            this.pictureBox1_4.Size = cardSize;
            this.pictureBox1_4.TabIndex = 1;
            this.pictureBox1_4.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox1_5
            // 
            var positionCard_5 = positionCard_4;
            positionCard_5.Offset(offset);
            this.pictureBox1_5.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(back, cardSize));
            this.pictureBox1_5.Location = positionCard_5;
            this.pictureBox1_5.Name = "pictureBox1_5";
            this.pictureBox1_5.Size = cardSize;
            this.pictureBox1_5.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1_5.TabStop = false;

            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_5)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_4)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_3)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1_1)).EndInit();
        }
    }
}
```

I also use a timer to display the cards so that they stagger.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: `mainPokerHand` is added to `main_hand_panel` and the other hands are all added to `extra_hands_panel`. Is it possible that `main_hand_panel` and `extra_hands_panel` are overlapping? or you've called Hide() (Visible = false) on `main_hand_panel` and that's why it doesn't show when you have multiple hands? Try setting the background colour of main_hand_panel to bright green then run the application and see what happens to the bright green panel.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem,
I was not clearing the controls between hand changes, so I was trying to update a panel that was in the background.  Controls.Clear() before moving to the next hand fixed that for me.  Sorry for the long post for nothing. :(

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered refreshing the entire form?

```
Form1.Refresh();
```

or only refresh the panel

```
PokerPanel.Refresh();
```